# Remove an activity from the stack

Tags: android, stack, android-activity

I have three activities ActivityA, ActivityB, ActivityC.

Suppose in ActivityA, there is some code like...

```
if(someCondition()){
gotoActivityB();
}
else{
gotoActivityC();
}
```

Now, If user goes to **ActivityB**, **ActivityA** should not be finished.

If he goes to **ActivityC**, it should be finished.

Adding `noHistory` in manifest file doesn't work.

Also, `finish()`in if condition doesn't work, As there are many activities after ActivityC in which ActivityA should be in background.

I don't want to call `startActivity(context,ActivityA.class)`in those activities `onBackPressed()` because, it will again execute code of `onCreate()` in **ActivityA**.

So, is there a way, where i can remove ActivityA from the stack when user presses back button in ActivityB?

may be something like this:?

```
ActivityB.this.finish();
ActivityA.finish(); //some code to finish ActivityA
```

Comment: doing this your application closes,as Activity A is the first activity in stack

Comment: @AkashG i know. Let the application close

Comment: <b>As there are many activities after ActivityC in which ActivityA should be in background.</b> then what is the purpose of finishing A if C is called?

Comment: Its a very big app, I can't explain the purose. I just gave an example. What i want is "Can I finish an activity which is in the stack from another activity?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here is one way you can accomplish your goal.  You will need to pass around the Activity context to wherever you need it in order to call finish() on it.  I used the Application class to do this.  I only used two classes to do it for the sake of time, but it should work just fine for your purposes.  Here is how I did it:

This is the first class.  It is the Activity that we want to close from another Activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private Button button;
// application instance
private MainApplication mainApplication;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainApplication = (MainApplication) getApplicationContext();
    // set the Activity's context for later usage.  Doing this determines which
    // Activity can be closed from another Activity.
    mainApplication.setActivityContext(this);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    }       
} 
}
```

This is the Second Activity.  Exiting out of it will also cause finish() to be called on the first class:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

private Activity activityContext;
private MainApplication mainApplication;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_activity_layout);

    mainApplication = (MainApplication) getApplicationContext();
    // get the Activity context you stored in the MainApplication class
    // so you can call finish on it.
    activityContext = mainApplication.getActivityContext();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // closes your defined Activity.  If you press the back button you will find
    // that you exit right out of the app as the other Activity gets popped off 
    // the stack.
    activityContext.finish();
}
}
```

And the Application class:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {

private Activity activityContext;

public Activity getActivityContext() {
    return activityContext;
}

public void setActivityContext(Activity activityContext) {
    this.activityContext = activityContext;
}

}
```

And of course make sure to declare your MainApplication class in the AndroidManifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

This is a sort of hacky way to do this.  There may be better ways.  But regardless, you have to pass around the context of the Activity that you want to call finish() on.  Then you can close it from anywhere.

Comment: Perfect!!! who cares whether its a hacky way or ethical way? My problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can finish your activity in current activity itself based on the condition. or use StartActivityforResult based on the result you can finish your activity.

hope this will help you.

Comment: Nope. this doesn't solve my issue. Once go through the complete question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in another way, like i do.

1. Create a static instance variable of the activity in the beginning.

   ```
   private static Activity1 thisAct = null; // Activity1 is name of class
   ```
2. Now initialize this variable in `onCreate()` method

   ```
   thisAct = this;
   ```
3. Create a static method which will finish this activity

   ```
   public static void finishActivity()
   {
       thisAct.finish();
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks. But its solved. So, I don't wanna disturb that again :)\

Answer (score -1):

While going to Activity C, clear the FLAG :

```
    Intent cIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), cActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    startActivity(cIntent);
```